# `operator<<` on a container which works for both values and references

Tags: c++, templates, ostream

There is a container class `container` which is templated, so it can contain anything.

I want to add ability to print its contents to `std::ostream` so I've overriden `operator<<`.

However this has a drawback: if the container contains references (or pointers), the method only prints addresses instead of real information.

Please consider this simple test code which demonstrates the problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <deque>

template<typename T, bool is_reference = false>
class container {
public:
    container() {}
    void add(T a) { queue.push_back(a); }
    
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const container<T, is_reference>& c) {
        for (const T& item : c.queue) {
            if (is_reference) out << *item; else out << item;
            out << ",";
        }
        return out;
    }
    
private:
std::deque<T> queue;
};


int main() {
    //Containers
    container<int*, true> myContainer1;
    container<int> myContainer2;
    
    int myA1(1);
    int myA2(10);
    
    myContainer1.add(&myA1);
    myContainer1.add(&myA2);
    
    myContainer2.add(myA1);
    myContainer2.add(myA2);
    
    std::cout << myA1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << myA2 << std::endl;
    
    std::cout << myContainer1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << myContainer2 << std::endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

I had an idea to provide an extra `is_reference` boolean in the template for adjusting the `operator<<`.

However this causes an early compiler error, in case I have *value type* container(s).

How can I make this work?

If I change the printer line to

```
out << item << ",";
```

The code compiles and prints this:

```
1
10
0x7ffd77357a90,0x7ffd77357a94,
1,10,
```

Obviously my goal is to have this result:

```
1
10
1,10,
1,10,
```

(How) can I achieve this easily?

Comment: Any of the c++ standard container classes may contain `std::any` or `std::variant<...>` value items, can you elaborate further about your requirements please?

Comment: First of all how are you going to keep reference in a container. Second - references are not printed as address, unless you mean something else by reference.

Comment: Overload the function. One where `container` holds pointers, one where it holds values.

Comment: This doesn't compile at all for me, because `*item` isn't well-formed when `T` is an `int`. If I change it to `if constexpr(is_reference)` so that it compiles at all, I [get](https://godbolt.org/z/EEx6EEEqq) the output you expect

Comment: @super: how exactly shall I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SFINAE to select an overload based on whether `std::is_pointer<T>::value` is `true` or `false`. This works already with C++11:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <deque>

template<typename T>
class container {
public:
    // container() {} // dont define empty constructor when not needed
    //                   or declare it as = default
    void add(const T& a) { queue.push_back(a); } // should take const&
    
    template <typename U = T, typename std::enable_if< std::is_pointer<U>::value,bool>::type=true> 
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const container<T>& c) {
        std::cout << "is pointer\n";
    }
    template <typename U = T, typename std::enable_if< ! std::is_pointer<U>::value,bool>::type=true>
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const container<T>& c) {
        std::cout << "is not pointer\n";
    }
    
private:
    std::deque<T> queue;
};


int main() {
    //Containers
    container<int*> myContainer1;
    container<int> myContainer2;
    std::cout << myContainer1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << myContainer2 << std::endl;
}
```

[Output](https://godbolt.org/z/6vaP81Tzv):

```
is pointer

is not pointer
```

Since C++17 you can use `constexpr if`. Also since C++17 there is `std::is_pointer_v` and since C++14 there is `std::enable_if_t`, both would make the code a little less verbose.

Comment: `std::is_pointer_v` is introduced in C++17 only, `std::enable_if_t` is in C++14.

Answer (score 1):

For the conditional choice between `item` and `*item` to work, you will need a compiler that supports the C++17 Standard (or later) and then use an `if constexpr (...)` statement.

Also, you can use [`std::is_pointer`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_pointer) to check whether the contained type is a pointer, rather than adding a 'flag' to your template:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <deque>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
class container {
public:
    container() {}
    void add(T a) { queue.push_back(a); }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const container<T>& c) {
        for (const T& item : c.queue) {
            if constexpr (std::is_pointer<T>::value) {
                out << *item;
            }
            else {
                out << item;
            }
            out << ",";
        }
        return out;
    }

private:
    std::deque<T> queue;
};
```

Comment: Or `std::is_pointer_v<T>`, for brevity

Comment: Can this solved with earlier (c++14) compilers too by any chance?

Comment: @Daniel Possibly, but with conditionally-templated versions of the operator using `enable_if`. Will have a think when I'm back on my PC.